# What is this 1055 Delphi Error and is it Important?

Tags: delphi, multithreading

I am using a FindFile routine to search through all files in a directory. The original code was freely available from [Latium Software](http://www.latiumsoftware.com/en/). It runs the FindFile is a separate Thread.

It has always worked fine, and still continues to work fine. But since I upgraded from Delphi 4 to Delphi 2009, it now gives a Warning:

```
W1055: Published caused RTTI ($M+) to be added to type '%s' (Delphi)
```

The error occurs at the "published" line of this thread declaration:

```
  TThread1 = class(TThread)
  private
    OwnerForm: TFindFileForm;
    procedure Initialize;
    procedure AddFileName;
    procedure Finalize;
  protected
    procedure Execute; override;
  published
    constructor Create(Owner: TFindFileForm);
    destructor Destroy; override;
  end;
```

The Delphi help states:

> You added a 'PUBLISHED' section to a class that was not compiled while
>   the {$M+}/{$TYPEINFO ON} switch was in
>   effect, or without deriving from a
>   class compiled with the
>   {$M+}/{$TYPEINFO ON} switch in effect.
>
> The TypeInfo standard procedure requires a type identifier as its
>   parameter. In the code above,
>   'NotType' does not represent a type
>   identifier.
>
> To avoid this error, ensure that you compile while the {$M+}/{$TYPEINFO
>   ON} switch is on, or derive from a
>   class that was compiled with
>   {$M+}/{$TYPEINFO ON} switch on.

Well, I didn't add the 'PUBLISHED' section. It's always been there. I'm not a component developer, and I really don't understand at all what this message means, whether or not it is really a problem, and what I should or should not do about it.

Is this important and if so, what should I do to fix it? Or should I just ignore it?

Comment: W1055 is not a error is a warning, just like you ask to be in your answer to Barry.

Comment: You *did* add a published section. That code didn't put itself there. Over the course of *eight* versions, Delphi has changed, including new RTTI, and with it comes some things worth warning about. You don't have to be a component developer to understand this. You're writing a class, whether you like it or not, so you owe it to yourself to understand the basic features of classes, including the visibility directives.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It adds some data to the executable and increases its size somewhat. In very rare cases it can be a reverse engineering risk, as it permits third parties (e.g. crackers) to see that the class supports the methods mentioned in the published section.

You can safely ignore it, or replace the `published` directive with `public` to make it go away.

Comment: Thanks, Barry. If I represent a typical Delphi programmer, then error messages such as these are not helpful to us, unless the recommendation of what to do is better. The Help didn't mention anything about changing published to public

Answer (score 11):

Barry's answer deals with the crux of this particular issue, but note that W1055 is not an "error", it's a WARNING (as indicated by the W).

The following prefixes are used in compiler output:

- Hnnnn - hints
- Wnnnn - warnings
- Ennnn - errors
- Lnnnn - linker errors
- Unnnn - unexpected(?) internal errors

I've listed these in order of relative severity and significance.  Hints and warnings generally don't affect your compilation - they tell you about consequences arising from things in your code.

Errors obviously are errors that prevent compilation.  Linker errors are relatively uncommon but indicate that although compilation was successful, something went wrong during linking.

U errors are the bad boys - you get these VERY rarely and they indicate that something went badly or unexpectedly wrong in the compiler itself.

As Barry said - in your case you could ignore 1055, since it is a warning that simply informs you of the consequences of using "published" in the way that it was found in your code.  It is generally a good idea to have a policyof "Zero warnings" (or hints) however, as then you can use the presence of a hint OR a warning in your compilation as a "red flag" that indicates a potential mistake in your code (the compiler interpreting something in a way that you perhaps did not intend.  e.g. in this case, you didn't MEAN to publish the method and have RTTI introduced onto your class).